# Is it safe to use a WindowSpec with an undefined frame in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window-functions

I often use Window-Functions in Apache Spark, for example to calculate cumulative sums. So far I never specified a frame as the output was correct. But recently I've read in a blog (https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html):

> In addition to the ordering and partitioning, users need to define the
>   start boundary of the frame, the end boundary of the frame, and the
>   type of the frame, which are three components of a frame
>   specification.

So I'm wondering if it's safe to use a unspecified frame, example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val df = (1 to 10000).toDF("i")

df
.select(
  $"i",
  sum($"i").over(Window.orderBy($"i")).as("running_sum1"),//unspecified frame
  sum($"i").over(Window.orderBy($"i").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)).as("running_sum2") // specified frame
)
.show()


+---+------------+------------+
|  i|running_sum1|running_sum2|
+---+------------+------------+
|  1|           1|           1|
|  2|           3|           3|
|  3|           6|           6|
|  4|          10|          10|
|  5|          15|          15|
|  6|          21|          21|
|  7|          28|          28|
|  8|          36|          36|
|  9|          45|          45|
| 10|          55|          55|
| 11|          66|          66|
| 12|          78|          78|
| 13|          91|          91|
| 14|         105|         105|
| 15|         120|         120|
| 16|         136|         136|
| 17|         153|         153|
| 18|         171|         171|
| 19|         190|         190|
| 20|         210|         210|
+---+------------+------------+
```

Apparently they give the same output, but are there cases where it's dangerous to use the unspecified frame? Using Spark 2.x by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.

Looking at the source code of the master branch for the `Window` object on [github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.scala#L36), there is the following note (it does not exist in the 2.3.0 branch):

> When ordering is not defined, an unbounded window frame (rowFrame, unboundedPreceding, unboundedFollowing) is used by default. When ordering is defined, a growing window frame (rangeFrame, unboundedPreceding, currentRow) is used by default.

In other words, when there is an ordering on the window, i.e. by using `orderBy`, an unspecified boundary on the frame is equal to having:

```
rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
```

In the case where `orderBy` is not used, the default is an entiery unbounded window:

```
rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

---

Further investigation shows that these defaults have been used since window functions were introduced in Spark 1.4.0, relevant [github branch](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/windowExpressions.scala#L235):

```
def defaultWindowFrame(
    hasOrderSpecification: Boolean,
    acceptWindowFrame: Boolean): SpecifiedWindowFrame = {
  if (hasOrderSpecification && acceptWindowFrame) {
    // If order spec is defined and the window function supports user specified window frames,
    // the default frame is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.
    SpecifiedWindowFrame(RangeFrame, UnboundedPreceding, CurrentRow)
  } else {
    // Otherwise, the default frame is
    // ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING.
    SpecifiedWindowFrame(RowFrame, UnboundedPreceding, UnboundedFollowing)
  }
}
```